# How to create a NetworkPolicy usingt he Fabric8 java client for Kubernetes

Tags: java, networking, kubernetes, fabric8

I am reading the Kubernetes docs here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

I would assume there is an equivalent object ofr a NetworkPolicy but I didnt find one in the source code or any examples setting the network policy on groups of pods.

Am I looking at the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of creating NetworkPolicy using fabric8 kubernetes client.

https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/976

To select group of pods you can use [PodSelector](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/976/files#diff-5f8b7a34612cefb425868d387e04fccaR31) in NetworkPolicySpec.

Comment: Hey Hrishikesh! Thanks for adding an example Just curious, is there a way to achive this without using the yaml resource? Is there a Network policy builder equivalent?

Comment: Sorry didnt see the complete example! Thank you so much!!

Comment: How do you set the policy types using the builder?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a handler for it in https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/handlers/NetworkPolicyHandler.java, so I guess it’s supported. The actual NetworkPolicy class seems to be in a dependency library, kubernetes-model.

Comment: Thank you for linking the related object

Comment: I am not sure how to set the type - ingress/egress using either the handler or the builder for NetworkPolicy?